# Fatal error desconocido PHP

Tags: php

Pues estaba trabajando en PHP y me sale un mensaje en la linea 69 del documento actual:

> Fatal error: in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\php_pruebas\app\config\database.php on line 69

```
public function Connect($host, $dbname, $user, $pass)
    {

        $this->host = htmlspecialchars($host);
        $this->dbname = htmlspecialchars($dbname);
        $this->user = htmlspecialchars($user);
        $this->pass = htmlspecialchars($pass);

        if (strlen($this->dbname) > 2 && strlen($this->dbname) < 50) {

            $this->dbname = filter_var($this->dbname, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);
        } else {

            return false; # Pendiente de excepcion
            $this->error .= 'Error en la dbname';
        }
        if (strlen($this->user) > 2 && strlen($this->user) < 50) {

            $this->user = filter_var($this->user, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);
        } else {

            return false; # Pendiente de excepcion
            $this->error .= 'Error en el usuario';
        }
        if (!$this->error || empty($this->error)) {

            $this->conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname, $this->user, $this->pass); -> linea 69
            return $this->conexion;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Si alguien me dice que significa ese error se lo agradeceria por favor

Comment: Probaste imprimir por consola o similar la cadena de conexión antes de usarla? De este modo podrías verificar que se esté generando correctamente.

Comment: Solo me muestra el fatal error

Answer (score 0):

Consulta el posible error que tienes usando try & catch:

```
try {
    $this->conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname, $this->user, $this->pass);
}catch(PDOException $e){
    print $e->getMessage();
}
```